# How to get a number from Solve

Tags: equation-solving

It's often useful to get just one number from `Solve`. I use the following construction for acquiring one solution from the expression returned by `Solve`.

```
q = t /. Solve[p == 2 t + 1, t][[1]]
```

Mostly I don't like to use the different variable name within `Solve`. And the rule-applying seems very unnatural. I think a solution that is more elegant must exist. Can anyone show me this?

Comment: `Solve[p == 2 t + 1, t][[1, 1, 2]]` ?

Comment: Wow, thank you, I'll serch for what does it mean...

Comment: Since you ask for the first solution you should use e.g. `s[[1, 1, 2]]` instead of `s[[All, 1, 2]]` etc. However you should remember that more flexible way is using `ReplaceAll`, e.g. here `t /. First @ Solve[..., t]`.

Comment: I feel closing this is fine, but I am glad I had the opportunity to post an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just extract second argument from `Rule` function by

```
Solve[p == 2 t + 1, t][[1, All, 2]]
```

Use `All` in case of more then one solution.

Comment: Thank you. Now it's a bit better. But the problem of the variable names is still exist

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what exactly you mean by "the problem of the variable names" (in the comments). Anyway you could construct a function like this (ignore the red syntax highlighting in the definition)

```
SyntaxInformation[solveAndAssign] = {"LocalVariables" -> {"Solve", {2, 2}}};
SetAttributes[solveAndAssign, HoldAll];
solveAndAssign[eqn_, var_Symbol] :=
 (
  var =
   Block[{var},
    var /.
     First[
      Solve[
       eqn
       ,
       var
       ]
      ]
    ]
  )
```

Example

```
q = 3;
solveAndAssign[p == 2 q + 1, q];
q
```

Outputs

> 1/2 (-1+p)

In the example above you see that you can use the variable you want to assign to in your equation. The code still works if you put your equation in a variable (the attribute `HoldAll` might make you think otherwise). Of course the equation has to formulated in terms of `q` rather than the value of `q`, which is why we `Clear` `q` for the moment.

```
Clear@q
eqn = p == 2 q + 1;
q = 3;
solveAndAssign[eqn, q];
q
```

Outputs

> 1/2 (-1+p)

**About the code**

I have made no effort to make this work with multiple variables. I suppose people might object to the variable having a color that implies it is local, while an assignment is made to that variable, which is valid. But I think the name of the function should make the intention clear.

The main point of this answer is to show how you could do something like this, I don't think the function is particularly useful.